# Derivation of the velocity distribution function in kinetic gas theory

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

I'm reading a book and got stuck at how one formula during the process of deriving the velocity distribution function.
$$
\Omega\left(v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z}\right)=f\left(v_{x}\right) f\left(v_{y}\right) f\left(v_{z}\right) \quad \text{(Eq.1)}
$$
The omega function describes the distribution of velocity for an ensemble of gaseous particles.
$$
\ln \Omega(\nu)=\ln f\left(\mathrm{v}_{x}\right)+\ln f\left(\mathrm{v}_{y}\right)+\ln f\left(\mathrm{v}_{z}\right) \quad \text{(Eq.2)}
$$
To determine the velocity distribution along 1 direction:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial \ln \Omega(\nu)}{\partial v_{x}}\right)_{v_{y} v_{z}}=\frac{d \ln f\left(v_{x}\right)}{d v_{x}} \quad \text{(Eq.3)}
$$
Using chain rule:
$$
\left(\frac{d \ln \Omega(\nu)}{d \nu}\right)\left(\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial v_{x}}\right)_{v_{y}, v_{z}}=\frac{d \ln f\left(v_{x}\right)}{d v_{x}} \quad \text{(Eq.4)} 
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}\left(\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial \mathrm{v}_{x}}\right)_{\mathrm{v}_{\mathrm{y}} \mathrm{v}_{z}} &=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathrm{v}_{x}}\left(\mathrm{v}_{x}^{2}+\mathrm{v}_{y}^{2}+\mathrm{v}_{z}^{2}\right)^{1 / 2}\right)_{\mathrm{v}_{y}, \mathrm{v}_{z}} \\ &=\frac{1}{2}\left(2 \mathrm{v}_{x}\right)\left(\mathrm{v}_{x}^{2}+\mathrm{v}_{y}^{2}+\mathrm{v}_{z}^{2}\right)^{-1 / 2} \\ &=\frac{\mathrm{v}_{x}}{v} \quad \text{(Eq.5)} \end{aligned}
$$
Substituting back into $(Eq.4)$ yield
$$
\begin{aligned}\left(\frac{d \ln \Omega(\nu)}{d \nu}\right)\left(\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial v_{x}}\right)_{v_{y} v_{z}} &=\frac{d \ln f\left(v_{x}\right)}{d v_{x}} \\\left(\frac{d \ln \Omega(\nu)}{d \nu}\right)\left(\frac{v_{x}}{\nu}\right) &=\frac{d \ln f\left(v_{x}\right)}{d v_{x}} \\ \frac{d \ln \Omega(\nu)}{\nu d \nu} &=\frac{d \ln f\left(v_{x}\right)}{v_{x} d v_{x}} \quad \text{(Eq.7)} \end{aligned} \quad \text{(Eq.6)}
$$

Im confused how $v$ and $v_{x}$ can be written in form of (Eq.7) because both $v$ and $v_{x}$ are functions of $v$ and i think product & quotient rules are needed for the left terms $
\left(\frac{d }{d \nu}\right)\left(\frac{\ln \Omega(\nu)\cdot\mathrm{v}_{x}}{\nu}\right)
$

Comment: I am a little confused by your confusion.  You show the whole derivation and I am not following why $v$ is a function of $v$.  Isn't $v$ just the speed?

Comment: @honeste_vivere which line are you referring to?

Comment: Your very last sentence.

Comment: @honeste_vivere yes it is. The aim is to use $
\Omega\left(v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z}\right)
$ to derive the Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution since based on the chain rule $$
\frac{d \ln f\left(\mathrm{v}_{j}\right)}{\mathrm{v}_{j} d \mathrm{v}_{j}}=\frac{d f\left(\mathrm{v}_{j}\right)}{\mathrm{v}_{j} f\left(\mathrm{v}_{j}\right) d \mathrm{v}_{j}}=-\gamma
$$

Comment: Intergration of the above term would give the velocity distribution along 1 direction $$
\begin{aligned} \int \frac{d f\left(\mathrm{v}_{j}\right)}{f\left(\mathrm{v}_{j}\right)} &=-\int \gamma \mathrm{v}_{j} d \mathrm{v}_{j} \\ \ln f\left(\mathrm{v}_{j}\right) &=-\frac{1}{2} \gamma \mathrm{v}_{j}^{2} \\ f\left(\mathrm{v}_{j}\right) &=A e^{-\gamma \mathrm{v}^{2} / 2} \end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I just dont know how (Eq.6) can be rewritten in (Eq.7)

Comment: The $(v_{x}/v)$ term is not the functional arguments of $\Omega$, they are just multiplied by the derivative term.  It's literally just two symbol gymnastic-steps from Equation 6 to 7.

Comment: @honeste_vivere thanks that clears things up for me